# How to fix 401 (Unauthorized)?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jwt

I have done jwt authorization and registration. But when checking whether the user is authorized, he issues 401 Unauthorized sent a request to receive a refresh token via axios

Here is the authorization verification action:

```
    export const checkAuth = () => {

    try {
        return async dispatch => {
            const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/refresh`, {withCredentials: true})

            //console.log(response)

            dispatch({
                type: SET_USER,
                payload: response.data
            })

        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.response?.data?.message);
    }
}
```

here is the reducer:

```
import {LOGOUT, SET_USER} from "../types";

const initialState = {
    currentUser: {},
    isAuth: false
}

export const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER:
            localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.accessToken);
            return {
                ...state,
                currentUser: action.payload,
                isAuth: true
            }
        case LOGOUT:
            localStorage.removeItem('token')
            return {
                ...state,
                currentUser: {},
                isAuth: false
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export const logout = () => ({type: LOGOUT})
```

Here is the app component:

```
import './App.css';
import {Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import LoginForm from "./component/LoginForm";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import RegisterForm from "./component/RegisterForm";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import {checkAuth} from "./redux/action";

function App() {
    const users = useSelector(state => {
        const {authReducer} = state
        return authReducer
    })

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    //console.log(users)

    useEffect(() => {

        checkAuth() // here I did dispatch()
    }, [])


    if (!users.isAuth) {
        return (<div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/registration" element={<RegisterForm/>}/>
                <Route path="/login" element={<LoginForm/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </div>)
    }

    console.log(users.currentUser)

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {users.isAuth ? users.currentUser.rows.map(data => <div key={data.id}>{data.email}</div>) : 'log in'}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here are the axios settings, but I tried using fetch() and the result is the same (401)

```
import axios from "axios";

export const API_URL = `http://localhost:5000/api`

const $api = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: API_URL
})

$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    return config;
})

$api.interceptors.response.use((config) => {
    return config;
},async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status == 401 && error.config && !error.config._isRetry) {
        originalRequest._isRetry = true;
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/refresh`, {withCredentials: true})
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken);
            return $api.request(originalRequest);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('NOT AUTHORIZED')
        }
    }
    throw error;
})

export default $api;
```

I installed cars on the server and call it like this

```
app.use(cors()) // Use this after the variable declaration / I tried such settings, it didn't help  {credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}
```

For some reason, a 401 error pops up, although everything works in postman!
Why don't I know anymore!???

Comment: You logic ned to authenticate with API to get a Bearer Token first
|| Then you inject it into headers while doing GET
|| On server side OPTIONS requets need to be handle on `API/refresh`, `API/registration` and `API/login`

Comment: @J-JacquesM Could you write more details please!!!

Comment: most browsers send OPTIONS request, mor einfos on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS || https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0, you need to reply those OPTIONS request. Postman is working because is not sending OPTION request to your server

Comment: @J-JacquesM I did this: app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true })) and app.options('*', cors()); The result is the same!